# MSDN Subscription for Job

Tags: software-industry, job-search

I was reviewing a job posting for C# developer and saw that they require:

```
Do you hold a valid MSDN subscription ?
```

I am not sure why a company would consider that, MSDN subscription is not cheap, currently I have one through my company and it is one of the most expensive one ($12,000).

My question is, Has anybody else seen such job requirement before ? and is it a sign to stay away from this job ?

This job is in Vancouver, Canada.

Comment: $12,000? Are you kidding me? That must be the company license, not the independent developer license. I don't know what the current price is, but based on past experience, it should be a lot lower. There is even a bizpark program where you can qualify for a free license for two years if you have a startup.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk There was one that is 12k and it grants they subscriber to lots of software and benes, like everything MS ever released It was called Ultimate.  It does not appear that option is available to new subscribers though similar benes are now offered with Enterprise with MSDN (6k to buy 2600 to renew)

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, I don't know if you have ever been involved in buying an ultimate subscription. The actual price for ultimate edition is $13,299 per year. [Source](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/03/31/visual_studio_2015_msdn_subscriptions/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're a to be a contractor (bring your own gear, work under your own direction), this is a very valid question to ask.  It tells them what resources you bring.

If you're going to be a contract employee, or a full-time employee, then they should be picking up the tab. However, they may want to just pick up your renewals instead of getting a new one.  I've had MSDN subscriptions off-and-on.  You probably want to read the fine print after you learn what they're intending to do.  If you're going to be a contract employee or full-time employee, I don't think you can use your own MSDN subscription for them.  If you're not sure, you should consult an attorney.